# Binary search - why do I need to subtract 1/add 1 everytime when changing the interval?

Tags: c, algorithm

I've been trying to understand how binary search works lately.

I've got this example.

```
int CautareBinara(int x)
{
    int Sol = -1, Left = 0, Right = N;
    while(Left <= Right)
    {
        int Mid = (Left+Right) / 2;
        if(V[Mid] == x)
        {
            Sol = Mid;
            break;
        }
        if(V[Mid] > x)
            Right = Mid - 1;
        if(V[Mid] < x)
            Left = Mid + 1;
    }
    return Sol;
}
```

I got it, I really understood how it works but there is one thing that I'm missing.

Why do I need to subtract 1/add 1 in the statements

```
Right = Mid - 1;
Left = Mid + 1;
```

Wouldn't it work only with Right = Mid and Left = Mid?

I really don't seem to get it.

I think that we do this because we've already tested v[Mid], so we can make the interval smaller by 1 unit. Is this the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you to take an example ( on paper) try solving it step by step using your algorithm just like your program would. It helps in understanding algorithms better sometimes.

Comment: "I think that we do this because we've already tested v[Mid], so we can make the interval smaller by 1 unit. Is this the reason?" - Yes.

Comment: @skrrrt thanks. I've done that, and that's the reason that I've said "I think that we do this because we've already tested v[Mid], so we can make the interval smaller by 1 unit.", but I was not completely sure.

Comment: Take a book and try to find page #123. Observe your decisions (maybe write them down).

Comment: i took a book and go to page #123. found nothing

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you have defined the interval as strictly between so can do the +-1 because you've tested the midpoint so it is no longer a possible answer.

But the other half is that you **HAVE** to do that because if you don't you can wind up with `Left+1=Right`, `Right = (Left+Right) / 2` and `V[Mid] > x`, and then you fail to make progress.  Landing you in the same situation...and an infinite loop.

The moral is this.  There are a lot of ways to code binary search.  But if you get the indexes even slightly wrong, there are lots of ways to get an infinite loop instead.